# How to change the font in file explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried

```
"explorer.fontFamily": "DejaVu Sans Mono"
```

Looking under suggested configuration options for file explorer I see nothing related to font.

Comment: Unfortunately, this feature is not available in `vscode`, you can do a `+1` to the feature request [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/519)